# MongoDB Fetching documents slow (Indexing used)

Tags: mongodb, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The FETCH-stage is the limiting factor in my queries. Ive been reaserching and it seems that mongodb is reading much more than it needs, and not utilize the bandwidth fully.

My mongoDB-mongod instance seems to be reading to much on a single query.
Testing on AWS EC2 m4.xlarge with 1 EBS io 5000Piops attached (100GB) SSD.
16 GB ram.

- The machine only contains the mongodb instance for testing purpose.
- The database is roughly 60GB (on Disk) in total ( several collections).
- The main collections is used in the following scenarios and queries.

db stats

```
db.stats()
{
    "db" : "database",
    "collections" : 4,
    "objects" : 406496932,
    "avgObjSize" : 326.3196544642064,
    "dataSize" : 132647938391,
    "storageSize" : 55475830784,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 5,
    "indexSize" : 8940408832,
    "ok" : 1
 }
```

collection summary:

```
db.collection.stats()  ->  
{    "ns" : "database.[collection###]",
    "count" : 367614513,
    "size" : 121155225858,
    "avgObjSize" : 329,
    "storageSize" : 52052197376,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : {"Left empty"},
    "nindexes" : 2,
    "totalIndexSize" : 8131604480,
    "indexSizes" : {
            "_id_" : 4373012480,
            "id_1_ts_-1" : 3758592000
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

The query:

```
db.[#######].find({ id : "######", 
   ts : { 
    "$gte" :
       ISODate("2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"), 
     $lt :
       ISODate("2016-10-07T02:00:00.000Z")
}}, {_id : 0,"u1"
     :1,"u2":1,"u3":1,"eq1" :1 ,"eq2" : 1,"eq3": 1,"ts" :1});
```

And the explain result:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "database.[collection]",
            "d" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "id" : {
                                            "$eq" : "#####ID#####"
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "ts" : {
                                            "$lt" : ISODate("2016-09-30T22:00:00Z")
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "ts" : {
                                            "$gte" : ISODate("2016-09-22T22:00:00Z")
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                    "transformBy" : {
                            "_id" : 0,
                            "u1" : 1,
                            "u2" : 1,
                            "u3" : 1,
                            "eq1" : 1,
                            "eq2" : 1,
                            "eq3" : 1,
                            "ts" : 1
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                            "id" : 1,
                                            "ts" : -1
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "id_1_ts_-1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                            "id" : [
                                                    "[\"#####ID#####\", \"#####ID#####\"]"
                                            ],
                                            "ts" : [
                                                    "(new Date(1475272800000), new Date(1474581600000)]"
                                            ]
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            },
            "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
            "executionSuccess" : true,
            "nReturned" : 676745,
            "executionTimeMillis" : 170508,
            "totalKeysExamined" : 676745,
            "totalDocsExamined" : 676745,
            "executionStages" : {
                    "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                    "nReturned" : 676745,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 167820,
                    "works" : 676746,
                    "advanced" : 676745,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 8970,
                    "restoreState" : 8970,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "transformBy" : {
                            "_id" : 0,
                            "u1" : 1,
                            "u2" : 1,
                            "u3" : 1,
                            "eq1" : 1,
                            "eq2" : 1,
                            "eq3" : 1,
                            "ts" : 1
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                            "nReturned" : 676745,
                            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 166470,
                            "works" : 676746,
                            "advanced" : 676745,
                            "needTime" : 0,
                            "needYield" : 0,
                            "saveState" : 8970,
                            "restoreState" : 8970,
                            "isEOF" : 1,
                            "invalidates" : 0,
                            "docsExamined" : 676745,
                            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                    "nReturned" : 676745,
                                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 980,
                                    "works" : 676746,
                                    "advanced" : 676745,
                                    "needTime" : 0,
                                    "needYield" : 0,
                                    "saveState" : 8970,
                                    "restoreState" : 8970,
                                    "isEOF" : 1,
                                    "invalidates" : 0,
                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                            "id" : 1,
                                            "ts" : -1
                                    },
                                    "indexName" : "id_1_ts_-                                                                   1",
                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                            "id" : [
                                                    "[\"#####ID#####\", \"#####ID#####\"]"
                                            ],
                                            "ts" : [
                                                    "(new Date(1475272800000), new Date(1474581600000)]"
                                            ]
                                    },
                                    "keysExamined" : 676745,
                                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                            }
                    }
            },
            "allPlansExecution" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
            "host" : "ip #########",
            "port" : 27017,
            "version" : "3.2.10",
            "gitVersion" : "79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317"
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

}

As we can see above mongoDb uses index. The IXSCAN takes **980ms** and the
FETCH  **~160000ms**.

If im not mistaking the whole read should be 676746(nReturned) * 329(avgObjSize ) Bytes = ~212 MB of data.

Ive notice that in the **iostats** (http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/iostat1.html) the following(/data/db is on xvdf):

```
  vg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.27    0.00    0.00   21.35    0.13   78.25
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rMB/s    wMB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
xvda              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
xvdf              0.00     0.00 1691.00    0.00    19.83     0.00    24.02     0.95    0.56    0.56    0.00   0.56  94.40
```

The rMB/s says ~20MB/s and this continious during the whole operation (fetch-stage). This means that mongodb is reading   160 s * 20MB/s =  3 200 MB, which is alot more than the 200 MB above.

Memory:

```
    free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
   Mem:         16048      12629       3418          0         32       4071
   -/+ buffers/cache:       8525       7522
  Swap:            0          0
```

Also mongodb not using the 5000 iops EBS provisioned, nor the bandwidth promised?
Only using ~1700 Reads/Second resulting in ~20MB/s.

Ive changed the read-ahead to 16KB. Ive tried placing journal and log at another HDD.

I cannot figure this out! 
Help me. 
Please!

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem when I was fetching around 35000 documents. To solve it, I used the aggregate function (`sakulstra:aggregate`) and in my case it has incredibly boosted the request. The result format is obviously not the same, but it's still easy to use to compute all things I need.

Before (7000ms) :

```
const historicalAssetAttributes = HistoricalAssetAttributes.find({
        date:{'$gte':startDate,'$lte':endDate},
        assetId: {$in: assetIds}
    }, {
        fields:{
            "date":1,
            "assetId":1,
            "close":1
        }
    }).fetch();
```

After (300ms):

```
const historicalAssetAttributes = HistoricalAssetAttributes.aggregate([
        {
            '$match': {
                date: {'$gte': startDate, '$lte': endDate},
                assetId: {$in: assetIds}
            }
        }, {
            '$group':{
                _id: {assetId: "$assetId"},
                close: {
                    '$push': {
                        date: "$date",
                        value: "$close"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 6):

The main facts are:

- The machine has 16 GB of RAM
- The collection in question is 112 GB uncompressed (~51 GB compressed)
- The collection's index total size is ~7 GB
- The collection contains 367,614,513 documents
- The bulk of time is spent fetching documents for projection. This takes 166470 ms (~166 seconds). Index scan for the query takes only 980 ms (<1 second).

Assuming WiredTiger cache is set to default, the amount of RAM reserved for the WiredTiger cache should be approximately 8.6 GB. In https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/faq/storage/#to-what-size-should-i-set-the-wiredtiger-internal-cache:

> Starting in MongoDB 3.2, the WiredTiger internal cache, by default, will use the larger of either:
>
> - 60% of RAM minus 1 GB, or
> - 1 GB.

From the information above, it appears that there is a memory pressure on your machine. MongoDB tries to keep indexes in memory for fast access, and the whole index is ~7 GB. This will effectively fill ~80% of your WiredTiger cache with just the index, leaving little space for anything else. As a result, MongoDB is forced to pull the documents in the result set from disk. At this point, performance suffers.

You can see the effect of this from the `iostat` output, where the device `xvdf` (where the data resides) hitting more than 94% utilization (shown in the `%util` column), which means that your operation is I/O bound as you don't have enough RAM to satisfy your ideal working set.

To mitigate this issue, you could try to:

- Provision a larger RAM for your deployment
- If applicable, use a cursor to return the documents instead of trying to access the whole result set all at once

You could also review the [Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/administration/production-notes/) and the [Operation Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-checklist-operations/) for recommended settings.

Comment: Hi! Ive tried using r3.xlarge (30.5GB ram). But the read from Disk is still to much. From iostat `rKB/s ~ 60000KB/s` and 20s gives me rougly **1.2 GB** of data read from disk (should be much less, ~0.2GB). Ive tried to divide the query in seperate cursors and that made it go a bit faster. Is there something else i can do to figure out the bottleneck of this performance issue?

Comment: It's hard to say without deep knowledge of your use case and deployment, especially since database tuning is a deep subject. I don't think looking at `rKB/s` is a good indicator. `util%` is more representative of how saturated your disk is. Also take a look at `mongostat`, especially the `%used` column, which will show the WiredTiger cache utilization. So far, all evidence points to the lack of RAM (i.e. your working set is too big for the amount of RAM you have) being the cause.

Comment: Hi, by increasing the RAM i made it work a bit better. Thank you for your reply.